# Navigation bar not showing after presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, presentviewcontroller

Hi there I used this code to move in to new contorller just with code and without segue .

```
    UIStoryboard * mainstoryb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * vc = [mainstoryb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"online_shop"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

how do I show Navigation bar or title bar on next view ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to present NavigationController as below :

```
 UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:ContactUSVCID];
 UINavigationController *objNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self presentViewController:objNav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want navigation bar, then you have to push not present

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];


      SecondViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"];
    /********if dont have navigation bar***********/
 UINavigationController *initialNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeNavCtrl_id"];
[self presentViewController:initialNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

/**********else*************/

```
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: I agree. This is the solution I settled on.

Answer (score 1):

Embed your ViewController in navigation controller and storyboard id to navigation controller then use this code

```
  UINavigationController *initialNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeNavCtrl_id"];
[self presentViewController:initialNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you present a view controller it will always be presented full screen.
Try this

```
UIStoryboard * mainstoryb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * vc = [mainstoryb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"online_shop"];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```